# URL loading issue in WKWebView

Tags: ios, webview

I'm getting a URL from API, I'm passing that URL to my webview and trying to load that, but it isn't loading. I don't know why but it isn't working. Even it's not showing any error or crashes. It's so weird but I don't know what I'm missing in that all the code is written fine. This is my code:

```
self.loadWeb(webURL: newsUrl!)
func loadWeb(webURL: String) {
    let url = URL(string: webURL)
    MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
    self.bgViewHeight.constant = webView.frame.size.height
}

private func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Start to load")
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
}
```

How i can load this?

Comment: Can show the actual URL which you got from APi!!

Comment: Some Tips :1) check for app transport security allow arbitrary loads
2) check if the URL is valid.3) check if web view is initialised properly and if the delegates method are called. 4) Check for authentication Challenge. You can also use  safari debugger Go to Safari > Developer > Simulator/Your Device, and you will be able to debug the page just like on desktop.